# It doesn't allow me to upload the app by 'App Store Connect Operation Error'

Tags: ios, xcode

I always get the error of the image every time I want to upload the application. I don't know what to do to solve it

Any ideas?

[image: picture]

Comment: Why if the bundle id of your app the same as the bundle id of some Cocoapod? It's seems you are trying to deploy something other than your app or your app is setup incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you register the bundle identifier?

If not, you can do so by

Navigating to [https://developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/)

On the left side,

select "Certificates, IDs and profiles"

Under "Identifiers", click "App Ids"

Click the plus button and register your bundle id.

Here you should enter the bundle identifier of your app (or something different, but if you choose to register a different one, you also have to adjust the identifier in Xcode).

I hope it help you.

Comment: I already have a certificate. The ID of my certificate is the same as the bundle identifier of my application. Is this ok or what do I have to do?